# AS3 Comparing 2 Arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, compare

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this problem. I have 2 unsorted arrays that need to be compared, array2 must contain all elements of array1 and array2 can any number of extra elements without affecting the result. I don't see any benefits from sorting the arrays and comparing the string values as array2 can have extra information causing noise.

```
var array1:Array;
var array2:Array;

// array2 must contain all elements of array1.

var array1:Array = new Array(1, 5, 6, 7);
var array2:Array = new Array(5, 9, 6, 4, 7, 8);
// comparing this should return false (array2 is missing and element from array1)

var array1:Array = new Array(1, 5, 6, 7);
var array2:Array = new Array(5, 9, 6, 4, 7, 1);
// comparing this should return true (array2 has all the elements of array1)
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function checkContent($needles:Array,$haystack:Array):Boolean
{
    for each(var item:Object in $needles) {
        if($haystack.indexOf(item) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Although correct, it is O(M*N), which is unneccesarily expensive.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks. I can't believe i missed that. Speed is not a major factor in  this case.

Comment: Imagine that $needles array is empty and result always will be true. Check length of arrays before cycle

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider putting your objects (if they are objects) in an object or dictionary.  That way you avoid the horrible scaling behavior from doing a comparison over all of the components.

Comment: I already considered using a dictionary but the specifics of the problematic as a whole negates the advantages.

Comment: @Maspuce Would you mind going into detail about how the Dictionary/Object paradigm won't work ?

Comment: It's not that it wouldn't work it's just not advantageous for my problem, I have elaborated in the comments of @Peter post.

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal solution would be to hash the items from the superset so that we can look them up in constant time. To do this we can use a `Dictionary`.

Then, we interate through the items in the subset to determine if they exist in the superset. Notice that we record the count, this ensures that we will also respect duplicate items.

The worst case complexity of this solution is O(M+N). However a failure case can complete with minimum O(M+1) since we break out of the second loop.

```
function compare(subSet:Array, superSet:Array):Boolean {

    // Assume true unless proven otherwise
    var retVal:Boolean = true;

    var map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    // Place all items from superSet into the dictionary map for constant time
    // lookup, also maintain a count for each item to record duplicates.
    var item:*;
    for each(item in superSet) {
        if(!map[item])
            map[item] = 0;

        // Increment the count for this item in the dictionary
        map[item]++;
    }

    for each(item in subSet) {
        if(map[item])
            // Item exists, decrement count.
            map[item]--;
        else {
            retVal = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I'm working with very small sets 1 to 5 averaging about 3, and as you said the worst case is O(M+N) but I can a best case of O(1+1) with a looping solution and I should save some overhead placing the elements in the dictionary. If I am wrong please let me know. I do have another area of the application that I think this solution would be perfect for, thanks.

Comment: You're actually absolutely correct! This solution may not be worth the effort if the arrays are small, in-fact this solution will incur more overhead if you only have about 1 to 5 items in your arrays. Unless you have thousands of items, or you're calling this comparison from inside another loop, the practical improvement is negligible/non-existant.

Comment: Since you will have so few elements in your arrays, I would actually recommend going with the solution @shanethehatt has provided. It is much simpler to read, works well, and introduces less complexity into your code. However, it does not detect duplicates like my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Array.every()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#every%28%29) and [Array.indexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#indexOf%28%29). However, even better perhaps might be to read a simple primer on [how Arrays work](http://digitalmedia.oreilly.com/helpcenter/actionscript30cookbook/chapter5.html) in ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

FlexFiend pointed you in the right direction. Dictionaries are great for such problems, as they have O(1) for key lookup/insertion.

```
function contains(superSet:Array, subSet:Array):Boolean {
    var element:*,
        map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    for each (element in superSet) 
        map[element] = true;
    for each (element in subSet)
        if (map[element] != true) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This runs in O(M+N), which is as good as it gets on unsorted arrays.